# How to cache routes when using Symfony Routing as a standalone?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, url-routing

I'm using the Symfony Routing components standalone, i.e. not with the Symfony framework. Here's my bare-bones code I'm playing with:

```
<?php
$router = new Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection();
$router->add('name', new Symfony\Component\Routing\Route(/*uri*/));
// more routes added here

$context = new Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext();
$context->setMethod(/*method*/);
$matcher = new Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher($router, $context);

$result = $matcher->match(/*requested path*/);
```

Is there a way to cache the routes, so I don't need to run all the `add()` calls on every page load? (See for example [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute).) I believe there is caching when using the full Symfony framework, can that be implemented easily here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Symfony Routing Component documentation contains an example of how to easily enable the cache: [The all-in-one Router](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html#the-all-in-one-router)

Basically your example can be reworked like the following:

```
// RouteProvider.php
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

$collection = new RouteCollection();
$collection->add('name', new Route(/*uri*/));
// more routes added here

return $collection;
```

```
// Router.php
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\PhpFileLoader;

$context = new RequestContext();
$context->setMethod(/*method*/);

$locator = new FileLocator(array(__DIR__));
$router = new Router(
    new PhpFileLoader($locator),
    'RouteProvider.php',
    array('cache_dir' => __DIR__.'/cache'), // must be writeable
    $context
);
$result = $router->match(/*requested path*/);
```